# Why is document.attachEvent false in Opera?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, opera

This is purely a puzzling curiosity.

I know that Opera supports IE's advanced event model (`attachEvent`), but why does `document.attachEvent` evaluate to false in this browser?

Comment: I would argue that IE's deprecated attachEvent model is not advanced... More importantly we've standardized on the addEventListener model and this I would only recommend using that - period. (With the exception of fallback support for older IE versions that didn't support the standard)

Comment: @scunliffe: I called it "advanced" because that is what it is (unofficially) called, in order to differentiate it from the traditional model. Yes, I agree, you should not need to use this event model in Opera, always favouring `addEventListener`, but that is not my question.

Comment: @gsnedders answer is spot on then... it was merely hidden to avoid accidental **presumption** that the browser was IE.  As noted though no code should even sniff for this (as it is obviously fragile) and attachEvent should not be used at all... even according to Microsoft: "The attachEvent method has been deprecated and samples have been removed. Microsoft recommends the use of addEventListener instead." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason as `document.all` has a stealthy existence everywhere except IE: to support sites that unconditionally use it, but to avoid going down legacy IE-only codepaths on websites which check it conditionally (which often use other non-standard IE things that aren't supported). This was introduced in 11.62, announced [here](http://my.opera.com/sitepatching/blog/2012/02/09/window-event-attachevent-detachevent-script-onreadystatechange); it seems noteworthy that `detachEvent` and `window.event` are also hidden.

As for why Opera does this and others don't: Opera historically supported it without hiding it, and while it was seen as desirable to remove it entirely, the legacy of Opera supporting it was too much to make that feasible, breaking code such as:

```
function _aspxAttachEventToElement(element, eventName, func) {
 if(__aspxNetscapeFamily || __aspxWebKitFamily)
 element.addEventListener(eventName, func, true);
 else { if(eventName.toLowerCase().indexOf("on") != 0) eventName = "on" + eventName; element.attachEvent(eventName, func); }
 }
```

(From [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/).)

```
if (d.opera)
    d.attachEvent("onmousewheel", j);
else
    d.onmousewheel = h.onmousewheel = j;
```

(From [krpano](http://krpano.com/).)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking it must be a "special case" as it was not playing by normal JavaScript rules, but couldn't find any references.

Comment: It should break the spec in the exact same ways as `document.all` does.